# append text instead of alert ID

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have been reading about $compile for the past few days and what i want to do now instead of showing an alert how to append some basic text?

```js
vgApp.directive('part', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true,
        template:'<div>the infor for each state</div>'
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.elementId = element.attr("id");
            scope.partClick = function() {
                alert(scope.elementId);
                element.append("some text here");
                $compile(element)(scope);
            };
            element.attr("ng-click", "regionClick()");
            element.removeAttr("part");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: The code is probably not working because the click handler calls `regionClick` and there is no function with that name. With directives, add click handlers with `element.on('click',` instead of compiling `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what its worth, here is the directive written to work without `$compile`:

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/pnQioYFcjArHs7uaHey4?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive('part', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true,
        template:'<div>the infor for each state</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //scope.elementId = element.attr("id");
            scope.elementId = attrs.id;
            scope.partClick = function() {
                alert(scope.elementId);
                element.append("some text here");
                //$compile(element)(scope);
            };
            //element.attr("ng-click", "regionClick()");
            element.on("click", function (event) {
              scope.partClick();
              scope.$apply();
            });
            //element.removeAttr("part");
            //$compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
}])
```

```css
.part {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.part:hover {
  border: 2px green;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Directive Example</h1>
    <div part id="part00" class="part">
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are compiling the directive element.  You might get unexpected behaviour this way, especially that you are removing attr 'part' which is a defining attribute.  I don't know what to expect from this, but it looks kind of scary.
I use compile to create new element, hook it up with Angular and attach it to the containing element as follows:

```
var popTpl = '<pop-it class="active CLASS_NAME no-ng-class="edtme|checkActive"></pop-it>'
            .replace('CLASS_NAME', cls);
popEl = $compile(angular.element(popTpl))($scope);
element.append(popEl);
```

Note: pop-it is a directive.  Hope it helps.

Comment: The OP is removing the `part` attribute to stop the $compile from doing infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but you shouldn't be in this situation in the first place.  Infinite loop is your first hint.  The second is the simplicity of design.  Notice, you are doing a lot of operations such as element.append(), element.attr(), etc.  if you use Angular approach you will find it is much easier and much more transparent to do this with much less code.  My switch from jQuery to Angular took about 3 months and it was painful,  I just couldn't drop my old habits.  But in the end I am very glad I did it.

Comment: It might be helpful to think like this.  If you define a directive with a template there is nothing to compile, Angular does it automatically.  Use compile to insert DOM elements into existing templates (with element as its root).  $compile is great for dynamically inserting/destroying DOM elements.  You can put in a loop and use it in place of ng-repeat; sometimes this approach makes sense.

Comment: I agree that the directive can be made to work without $compile. Show the OP how to do that. "Don't do it because it looks scary" is not a great answer.